# Finding voronoi next neighbors in periodic boundary conditions

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, nearest-neighbor, voronoi

I need to find the voronoi next neighbors for a given point, i.e. all points having voronoi cells that touch the original particle's cell.
The geometry is two-dimensional and periodic boundary conditions are used.
What is the best way to accomplish this (with or without the use of external libraries)?

Comment: The [CGAL](www.cgal.org) library provides a [2D periodic triangulation](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Periodic_2_triangulation_2/) package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
foreach ($this->indices as $key => $arr)
  {
     foreach ($this->indices as $ikey => $iarr)
     {
        if ($key != $ikey)
        {
           if ( ($arr[0]==$iarr[1] && $arr[1]==$iarr[0]) ||
                ($arr[0]==$iarr[2] && $arr[1]==$iarr[1]) ||
                ($arr[0]==$iarr[3] && $arr[1]==$iarr[2]) ||

                ($arr[1]==$iarr[1] && $arr[2]==$iarr[0]) ||
                ($arr[1]==$iarr[2] && $arr[2]==$iarr[1]) ||
                ($arr[1]==$iarr[3] && $arr[2]==$iarr[2]) ||

                ($arr[2]==$iarr[1] && $arr[3]==$iarr[0]) ||
                ($arr[2]==$iarr[2] && $arr[3]==$iarr[1]) ||
                ($arr[2]==$iarr[3] && $arr[3]==$iarr[2]) 

              )
           {
              $this->voronoi[$key][$ikey]=array($this->cc[$key], $this->cc[$ikey]); 
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: which language is this?

Comment: The code finds all voronoi cells from a delaunay triangulation.

Comment: I understand, but written in which programming language?

Comment: It's PHP programming language.